# Cloudera CDH Mac

Tags: macos, hadoop, cloudera

I am enrolled in a class that will be using Cloudera CDH and Hadoop, etc.

The current set-up for the class involves using a virtual machine with VirtualBox.

I am just wondering if there is a faster, more efficient implementation of the program that I can use. Can the program somehow be installed in my native environment instead?

(I am using a 2017 Macbook Pro with OS High Sierra)

Answer (score 4):

You can install Hadoop, Spark, Hive, Pig, in your Mac Os in the so-called pseudo-distributed mode. It is an installation in your local machine in which every node of the "cluster" is a Java Virtual Machine. 
The starting point is the Hadoop installation, you can follow this tutorial:

https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/big-data/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan.html

There are many tutorials on installing other part of the Hadoop ecosystem in mac OS, at least for El Capitan. (I did not experience any issue on following them on High Sierra).

The Hadoop experience you have in Cloudera or MapR or other sandboxes is totally different. Very smooth. You run Hue and start coding from there: you have Impala (not yet available for Mac OS), Hive, Sqoop, Pig editor and many other services working on the HDFS already set for you. Everything is ready to be exploited. You just start all the services from the Cloudera manager opening the Firefox browser in the VM and you can start analysing the data. In terms of learning, and I think this is what you might care about in this stage, this is the most efficient way.

A bit more efficient way to install Cloudera Quick start is using **Docker**. First download the community edition for Mac at:

https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac

Then from terminal type:

```
docker pull cloudera/quickstart
```

and follow the installation at:

https://store.docker.com/community/images/cloudera/quickstart

You will see that it runs more efficiently and it is more stable than the VM.

Efficiency in computational sense, comes with cloud services. You can use AWS, Azure, GCP, or other cloud providers and experiment the real power of Hadoop in a second stage. There are many offers for free experimenting cloud services, but they are limited in time or in free credits (in terms of $) you can spend. So I would suggest to go there after having acquired the most important skills.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the program somehow be installed in my native environment instead?

Yes, Hadoop can be installed on your Mac. No, CDH has no DMG for macOS.

Will that be the same as running CDH? No, there is no Cloudera Manager, Hue, Hive, HBase, Sqoop, Pig, Spark, etc.

Each of those extra tools would need to be installed separately.

The "faster, more efficient" alternative would be to use a dedicated CDH cluster that is external to your Mac.